# Objects on a grid in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to make objects move on a chessboard (a coordinate grid). I've defined these object as Vehicles. They have a position (x,y) on the plane and a direction. Being forced to move only North-South-East-West possible directions could be

1. North: (0, 1)
2. South: (0, -1)
3. East: (1, 0)
4. West: (-1, 0)

Vehicles can proceed only step by step (x+1, y), (x, y+1), where x, y are integers. **Two vehicles cannot stand in the same position**. A vehicle maintains its direction while it is possible, that is while it encounters an occupied position.

So I have to create a void move function which has as arguments the positions of the nearby vehicles (North South East West). Such a function should:

1. Check if the vehicle can maintain its direction and, if it can, refresh the vehicle position with the new position;
2. If the cell is occupied, go for another direction, check if the cell in that direction is free...
3. If every cell surrounding the vehicle is occupied, stay still.

I wrote a code that accomplish point 1 but I have difficulties with point 2. In particular, I can't think about an effective way to change the Vehicle's direction. Here's my code so far:

```
class Vehicle {
private:
    int x, y;
    int vx, vy;
public:
int getx() { return x;}
int gety() { return y;}
int getvx() { return vx;}
int getvy() { return vy;}

void sety(int a) { y = a;}
void setx(int a) { x = a;}
void setvx(int a) { 
    if (a != 0) {   
        vx = a / abs(a);
    }else { vx = a;}
} 
void setvy(int a) { 
    if (a != 0) {   
        vy = a / abs(a);
    }else { vy = a;}
}

void move(Vehicle * v) {
    int big = 0;
    while(big<4) {
        int cont=0;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if (x+vx != v[i].getx() or y+vy != v[i].gety()) {
                cont ++;
            }
        }
        if(cont==4) {
            x = x + vx;
            y = y + vy;
            break;
        } else { 
            big ++;
            // CHANGE DIRECTION in PROPER WAY
        }
    }
}

void print() {
    // prints the private members 
}

};
```

How could I improve the while?

Comment: Choose a random permutation of {North, South, West, East} (you may exclude his current direction) then, for each of those (in order), check whether the vehicle may go that way (if yes, break and go that way, otherwise, stand still and retry at the next step)? Btw, out of curiosity, what is the required behaviour if you have two vehicles coming from different directions a single cell apart (I mean there's a single free cell between them, e.g. >_<)? Does one of them enter the cell (which?) or do they both change direction if able?

Comment: Could you add a few lines to main with something that proves that your code is wrong, so that we can help you fix it? It's unclear to me why you loop over four vehicles v[i].

Comment: @Caninonos Thank you! I have to implement another class, named Traffic, that controls a list of Vehicles. A public method of Traffic will be a function that makes the vehicles move, one by one, so that the first one called by Traffic would occupy the free cell, and the other would find the cell occupied. In a certain sense the first vehicle that moves wins.

Comment: @Johan I posted on code review the whole code, if you want to check it out, maybe it's clearer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190991/moving-objects-on-a-grid-in-c